# Trouble with FileStats class

Tags: java

I am having a bit of trouble Using the FileStats class to show how many lines the file has and how many lines contain the text. I have been able to successfully show how many lines the file has but I keep getting the incorrect answer to how many lines contain the text.

For Example if a file contains 5268 lines, and 1137 of those lines contain the word "the", my code returns output saying it only contains 553 of those lines contain the word "the".

Any help would be appreciated Thank you. Code is Below

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
public class Romeo

{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in); //creating object for scanner class
        System.out.println("Enter a filename");
        String file_name=input.nextLine(); //asking user to enter a file name


        int word_line_count=0,line_count=0; //count variables for counting the line count and word occurance count
        String search_word=input.nextLine(); //asking user to enter a search_Word
        File f=new File(file_name); //Creating File Descriptor for reading input file
        String[] words_sentence=null; //creating string which stores the all words in a line
        FileReader file_object = new FileReader(file_name); // Creating File Reader object
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file_object); //Creating BufferedReader object
        String sentence;

        while((sentence=buffer.readLine())!=null) //Reading Content from the file till the end of file
        {
            words_sentence=sentence.split(" "); //Split the sentence by using space delimiter
            for (String word : words_sentence) //itearte for each loop for every word in sentence
            {
                if (word.equals(search_word))
                {// if word in the sentence equals to search word increment the count valie
                    word_line_count++;
                    break; //if one word is equal in the sentence break the loop because no need to check entire sentence
                }
            }
            line_count++; //increment line count for every while loop iteration
        }

        System.out.println(file_name + " has " + line_count + " lines"); //printing the line count

        System.out.println("Enter some text");

        System.out.println( word_line_count+ " line(s) contain" ); //printing the number of lines contains the given word
        file_object.close(); //closing file object
    }
}
```

Comment: Minimize the file down to a single line on which the program doesn't work. Just in case, you ignore punctuation (e.g. you won't detect `the.`) and upper-case variations (`The`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it so complicated. There's a simple method in the String class that will help you to solve this problem much easier: contains()

Take a look at the if statement below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //creating object for scanner class
    System.out.println("Enter a filename");
    String file_name = input.nextLine(); //asking user to enter a file name


    int word_line_count =0, line_count=0; //count variables for counting the line count and word occurance count
    String search_word = input.nextLine(); //asking user to enter a search_Word
    File f = new File(file_name); //Creating File Descriptor for reading input file
    String[] words_sentence = null; //creating string which stores the all words in a line
    FileReader file_object = new FileReader(file_name); // Creating File Reader object
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file_object); //Creating BufferedReader object
    String sentence;

    while((sentence=buffer.readLine())!=null) //Reading Content from the file till the end of file
    {

            if (sentence.contains(search_word))
            {
                word_line_count++;
            }

        line_count++; //increment line count for every while loop iteration
    }

    System.out.println(file_name + " has " + line_count + " lines"); //printing the line count

    System.out.println("Enter some text");

    System.out.println( word_line_count+ " line(s) contain" ); //printing the number of lines contains the given word
    file_object.close(); //closing file object
}
```

Comment: This works much better but I believe my code is ignoring   punctuation (e.g. it won't detect the.) and upper-case variations like (The).